# Automatic call of on-click function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to call a `onclick` function forcefully.

```
$('.checkbox-selector').click(function() {

});

$('.checkbox-selector1').click(function() {

});
```

When a control goes to the first function, the second function should be called automatically
i.e. onlick event is triggered.

Comment: Just as an aside, you can block your code with four spaces, as opposed to back ticks, for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Did you [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+trigger+click) before you asked this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it is exactly you're looking for, but I'd guess:

```
$('.checkbox-selector').click(function() {
    /* all sorts of stuff*/
    $('.checkbox-selector1').click();
    //or:
    $('.checkbox-selector1').trigger('click');
});

$('.checkbox-selector1').click(function() {

});
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 3):

```
function func1(e) {
    // do stuff for selector

    // run func2 too!
    func2();
}

function func2(e) {
    // do stuff for selector1
}

$('.checkbox-selector').click(func1);
$('.checkbox-selector1').click(func2);
```

Is this what you mean?

---

If so, make sure to look at the comments! They contain quite valuable information considering events and such.

You can replace `func2();` with `$('.checkbox-selector1').trigger('click');` to trigger the native event handler too! Using `$('.checkbox-selector1').triggerHandler('click');` is practically the same as `func2();`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: This is much better solution seeing as `.trigger("click")` will call the native `.click()` method on the element which could have other side effects. See what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Kfmd/1/ . In chrome the second checkbox gets checked as a result of what I just explaind.

Comment: @Esailija, It's not a (negative) side effect if you ask me. It entirely depends on the project but if you want to mimic a user click having a checkbox actually checked is 100% correct imo.(that aside, writing clean functions for this is often nicer)

Comment: Well the op didn't mention anything about needing to check the checkbox, just calling another function where `.trigger` is inappropriate.

Comment: I have to admit, I miss read that part at first. But without knowing the full context of the code trigger can still be a good option.(+1 on this answer from me too because of how it often should be coded)

Comment: @Esailija: If you only wanted to call event handers bound by jQuery, you could use `.triggerHandler`: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/.

Comment: @FelixKling wow, how did I not know about that. I have seen it in source code but always ignored it because it didn't look like an interesting function.

Comment: Added a line in my answer to make sure whoever reads my answer reads the comments too!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jQuery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function